# fingerprint alignment

Tags: matlab, alignment, fingerprint

I want to align two fingerprint images in matlab so that they can be matched using fuzzy vault. Kindly help me.

```
% read two images
Im1 = imread('input_2.tif');
Im2 = imread('input_3.tif');

%  convert images to type double (range from from 0 to 1 instead of from 0 to 255)
Im1 = im2double(Im1);
Im2 = im2double(Im2);

% Calculate the Normalized Histogram of Image 1 and Image 2
hn1 = imhist(Im1)./numel(Im1);
hn2 = imhist(Im2)./numel(Im2);

% Calculate the histogram error
f = sum((hn1 - hn2).^2);
f; %display the result to console

[i,j]=samplealign(hn1,hn2);
```

Comment: You should probably be more specific what you are having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `imregister`, for examples see this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregister.html) (third section )

you can also try this tool from the file exchange: [FingerPrint Application](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16728-fingerprint-application)